# How to get all filenames in a directory and place them in a text file with Perl?

Tags: perl, filenames

I have been trying to write a perl script to get all of the filenames from a directory and then place each name into a text file.

I was wondering if any good perl programmers could help me out with this. Sorry if I'm asking you to write the script, but I am sure someone could figure out how to do this in only a few lines.

Comment: Do you just want all the filenames in a text file or is there something else your perl script does? If it's just the list of names, you can simply do 'ls -1 > list.txt' in *nix or 'dir /B > list.txt' in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do:

```
perl -le 'for (glob(".* *")) {print if -f}'
```

Comment: This skips files whose names start with `.`, and it prints all the file names concatenated together with no newlines.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Fixed to include hidden files; otherwise the '-l' switch adds the newlines needed.

Comment: KeithThompson : No problem; thanks for reminding me that hidden files should be returned too.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do this in Perl for some reason:

```
  opendir DIR, '/some/dirname'         or die "$!";
  open FILE, '>', '/some/outputfile'   or die "$!";
  print FILE "$_\n" while readdir DIR;
  close FILE;
  closedir DIR;
```

*edited to put newlines in the output file… oops!*

To make it more general-purpose, you could do other things with the filename, by splitting the middle bit up:

```
  my $filename = readdir DIR;
  # do something with $filename
  print FILE $filename, "\n";
```

The first example takes advantage of Perl's `$_` pronoun, instead.

But, as @Ronin420 pointed out, it's far easier to do `ls -a1 /some/dirname > /some/outputfile` (with stdout redirected to a file, `ls` will add the `-1` itself, as well)

Comment: `ls` is great until the file names include blanks, tabs, newlines, and other such stuff.  Newlines in file names in particular cause grief.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately as-asked, he's getting a newline-delimited file out regardless … :-( At least `$filename` would be pure; but writing the names out `\n`-delimited will break for filenames containing `\n`.

Comment: Unlike `ls`, this prints the file names in some arbitrary order.  That's easily fixed by storing the result of `readdir` in an array and applying `sort` to it.